# How to count uppercase vowels and lowercase vowels in a string one time input?

Tags: java

I have created a program in Java to count lowercase vowels, but I'm not able to count uppercase vowels.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    //String input = new String(input.toUpperCase(0));
    System.out.print("Enter tha Letter: ");
    char x = input.next().charAt(0);
    if(x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u'){
        System.out.println("Vowel");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Consonant");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried repeating your logic in the if-statement for 'A', 'E', etc?

Comment: just convert the string to either lowercase or uppercase

Comment: `"aeiou".contains(input.next().toLowerCase())`

Answer (score 2):

You could have a string containing your vowels and then check whether it contains the first char of the input:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";

System.out.print("Enter tha Letter: ");
char x = input.next().charAt(0);

if(vowels.contains(Character.toString(x))){
    System.out.println("Vowel");
}else{
    System.out.println("Consonant");
}

input.close();
```

Alternatively, reduce `vowels` to `"aeiou"` and lowercase the input character using `Character.toString(x)`. But I personally like the other way better.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a final string of `aeiouAEIOU` and search and check if its a vowel

Since `aeiouAEIOU` has a fixed length the time complexity to check for a vowel is `O(1)`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        //String input = new String(input.toUpperCase(0));
        System.out.print("Enter tha Letter: ");
        String x = input.next().substring(0, 1);

        final String vowels = "aeiouAEIOU";
        if(vowels.contains(x)){
            System.out.println("Vowel");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Consonant");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply append the conditions for Uppercase vowels in your existing if condition :

```
if(x=='a' || x=='e' || x=='i' || x=='o' || x=='u' || x=='A' || x=='E' || x=='I' || x=='O' || x=='U'){
        System.out.println("Vowel");
}
```